# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, textbox, getelementbyid

I am trying to set a value of a textbox and I get this error...
Please see my code:

**this is my textbox**

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server"/>
```

**this is my drop down list**

```
<select id="title" name="D1" onchange="Select()" >
                <option selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">Pilot</option>
                <option value="5">Engineer</option>                                    
             </select>
```

**And that is my function**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


    function Select() {

        var ddl = document.getElementById("title");
        var selected = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("Text1").value = selected;
        alert(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
        if (selected == "5") {
            document.getElementById('divTechnician').style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('divTechnician').style.visibility = "hidden";

        }            
    }
</script>
```

Error occurs when I try to assign value to this text box

```
document.getElementById("Text1").value = selected;
```

Comment: I don't see the `divTechnician` ID anywhere.

Comment: That is irrelevant, divTechnician is not causing problems

Comment: I don't get it it's working fine in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/deyus/1/edit)

Comment: Please make sure that text box is present on the page at the moment when you're changing selector value. In Chrome developer tools, try executing document.getElementById("Text1").

Comment: There is no error in your javascript.

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I tested in IE11 and in chrome. Both browsers return the alert with the correct value.

Comment: I am using asp.net
See Mr.Cocococo answer below, that is the solution

Comment: tell me why are people giving me minus points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set clientidmode=static to this element

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" clientIdMode="static"/>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you !
that was just what i was missing

Comment: You should not define the `clientIdMode` on one specific control. It is bad practice and will certainly give you problems in the future.